# Index scan in query

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-server-2014

I have a query as below:

```
;With P As 
(Select CP.ProductID
From CatProduct CP
Join Product P On CP.ProductID = P.ProductID
Join ProductType pt with(nolock)     
On P.ItemType = pt.ProductTypeID    
And pt.IsOnline = 1 
Where 
CP.CategoryID = 1234
And p.Active = 1 And p.ActiveOnline = 1
And P.ApproveForOnline = 1 
)
Select P.ProductID,ISNULL(inv.QTYonHand, 0) 
From P
Join Inventory AS inv On inv.ProductID = P.ProductID and inv.WarehouseID = 1
```

`Inventory` table has `ProductID + WarehouseID` as its primary key.

`WarehouseID` value can be only 1 or 2 in the table.

Total number records with `WarehouseID = 1` is around 240K.

Query plan does an index scan on the PK and uses only `WarehouseID` as predicate. As a result, it processes all 240K records.

How can I write query so that both `WarehouseID` and `ProductID` are used as predicates and so only those 600 records are read and processed from the `Inventory` table?

I have confirmed that all statistics are up-to-date.
---Adding execution plan from both DEV And PROD:

DEV:
[image]

As you can see above, only the records from CTE get fed for Inventory table. That's what I want to happen in PROD..but it is not working.

PROD:
[image]
Please let me know if I need to provide more info.

Thanks in advance

Comment: that will depend on the distribution of WarehouseID values : if half the values are 1, the only way an index will be used , will be if it's a covering index. You haven't shown all the columns you are selecting...

Comment: Hi Mitch, around 97% records are with WarehouseID =1, rest are with value 2. I am actually selecting ProductID and Qty Columns only. My concern is that my CTE is giving only 600 records, so why is inventory table not working with those 600 records only...I also tried to make another index with WarehouseID, ProductID INCLUDE (Qty). It is doing Index Seek,.. but still giving 240K records as output

Comment: suggest you post your plan

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I am using Microsoft SQL Server version 2014

Comment: An index on a field with only two values, 97% of which are the same, is rarely likely to be very helpful, unless you have lots of queries for the value with only 3%. Are you sure ProductId is listed first in this index?

Comment: yes @JoelCoehoorn, ProductID is listed first in the index. I also tried making another index with (WarehouseID, ProductID) INCLUDE (Qty). I get same result in both cases.